# iTunes: fix 2000 tracks that the database no longer recognizes correctly

Tags: itunes

Over the past few years, iTunes has repeatedly tried to 'organize' my library, copying tracks from one place to another. When it then came back and scanned for files again, suddenly I had three copies of hundreds of songs.

A couple of days ago I deleted a stack of folders containing redundant songs, so I can return to a clean no-copy library in the *Music* folder.

I now have 2000 'dead tracks'. I have tried *Bring Out Yer Dead* and *PowerTunes* but neither have helped in fixing any more than one track at a time. It is amazing to me that it doesn't work when the vast majority of my collection is named *Artist - Title*. Why is this so difficult for these programs to find?

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: When you say "dead tracks", do you mean tracks that are listed in iTunes but have an exclamation icon next to them to indicate that they don't point to a file any longer?

Also, which version of iTunes?

Comment: @NadyneRichmond I mean tracks that iTunes has 'lost track of' but which still exist. I'm running iTunes 11.0.2.

Comment: Are the missing tracks still checked (see view options)? If not, you can at least sort a list view by checked, and get them all in on big selectable chunk.